# CodeIgniter CRUD structure

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure

I'm using Codeigniter to flesh out a pretty large project (especially for a n00b). One issue I'm having is how to organise my files and methods. I've broken my project down into features - the app is a task management software so already we have basic features such as "Task", "Project", "User" etc.

The way I intend to do this is by creating controllers for each and then following CRUD methodology in each. So for example in Task we would have the following methods:

```
create()
read()
update()
delete()
```

This makes sense in my head. Now in terms of Views, should I have multiple views, or should I combine create and update into the same form? Also, where does non-View functionality go, such as setting cookies etc?

This is quite a specific question but if anybody has any more holistic guides on general structure convention for CodeIgniter projects I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you got it right. This is what I do.

I tend to use the same view for create and update, keep it DRY (don't repeat yourself) if you can.

Non-view related stuff that does not handle anything business-related goes in what I call helper-classes. If it's business related, I put all the logic into services, so I can unit-test them without being dependant of any framework (not sure how new you are at this, but oh well :) ).

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'm very familiar with the DRY concept, it's something I try to consider with CSS (I'm really a front-end dev). Think I need to look deeper into the helper classes though.

Comment: Then I'm sure you're utilizing something like SCSS or LESS for your CSS needs? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Grocery Crud](http://www.grocerycrud.com/), a library that provides out of the box CRUD functionality for codeigniter.

It handles pretty good 1->n and n->n relationships so its convenient for small projects.

I don't know if you are familiar with it. If not give it a try. It will save you tons of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

My controller consists of these methods, which follows REST API guidelines:

- **read** -> get all records.
- **find** -> find record by primary key/id.
- **create** -> show the form view.
- **store** -> insert data from the form into the database.
- **edit** -> show the form view, populated with current records' data.
- **update** -> update data from the form into the database.
- **delete** -> delete data from the database.

This is called Resourceful Controllers.

Yes, you can combine create and edit in same form. However, there are cases those require you to use different create and edit form. In that case, just make 2 separate forms.

And... like @Theodore suggested, GroceryCRUD is worth a try if you don't need too many customizations.